# Traveller 5: Where do I find the list of knowledges that I can chose from after attending ANM School?

Tags: traveller-5

I'm using v5.09 in PDF.

Where do I find the list of knowledges that I can chose from after attending ANM School?

Comment: What is causing the problem? Is it hard to find or otherwise confusing? Give us something to work with.

Comment: I could not find it anywhere. Searched the pdf to find all mention of ANM School, and checked every section it was mentioned, to no avail. However, it all became obvious once I understood that ANM was not an abbreviation for a school, but an abbreviation for Army School or Navy School or Marin School.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ANM = Army, Navy, Marine. Each of the schools are listed under academy on page 40 of v5.09. You'll find the respective A for army in the Academy column and N for navy and so on.

The table is labeled "Character Generation C: Education"